# UITableView, need to freeze first cell(s)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using `UITableViewController` in order to use static cells.

Is there any way to freeze **first** cell so it's not scrollable? I'd like to other cells to scroll but first one to stay intact.

I was thinking about regular `UIViewController` with some stuff on top and `UITableView` under, but this won't work because I need `UITableViewController` in order for static cells to work.

The only other way to make it work is with `UIView`s and Scroll view, but then I don't get benefit of `UITableView`.

Is that possible?

EDIT:

Just to make it clear. I like to use `UITableView` with static cells because I have outlets and actions. Buttons, fields inside cells. I'd like to limit "coding" only to show/hide cells. I don't want to create UI inside code. I want to do as much as I can using Storyboard.

Not sure how to put views on section header using Storyboard. Is it possible at all? I only can set text caption.

Also! Even though I do have header (with test) it still scrolls with rest of cells. I need to make sure it stays on a screen.

Comment: The best way to do this would be to have the first row actually be a section header instead of a row.

Comment: Agreed. However if you're looking for the header view to itself function like a UITableViewCell, you'd need to set up another 1 cell UITableView with this first, unscrollable cell. This means you'll need to account for the two existing table views in all of your UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewDataSource methods.

Comment: If, for some reason, using a section header doesn't work for you, there are a couple of other ways to do this. One would be to use a UIViewController and a table view with dynamic cells -- there's nothing you can do with static cells that you can't also do with dynamic ones. Another way, would be to use a UIView controller with a view on top, and a container view underneath that would be house a UITableViewController with your static cells.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to add views to header using Storyboard. And this header scrolls with other cells. Anything I'm missing? See EDIT on original question

Answer (score 1):

You can use this delegate method and pass your custom view along with your sub control it will get stick at top :

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return <your custom view>;
}
```